# Custom ListView with Scrolling

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, scrollview

I am facing a problem in custom listview where i am having 10 rows of values displayed inside the textview from db.
When i scroll the list the items are duplicated.
Consider that i have number of rows named from 1 to 10.
if i scroll it, the rows are duplicated as 1,2,3,4,5,1,6,7,8,9,2,3,etc.. the same values are again displayed. I don't know why this occurs. If i remove 5 items and disable scrolling, then it does not have any sort of issues.
Adding more number of rows with scrolling enabled arises this issue.

```
  private class ItemLayoutListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context context;
    Hold myHold;
    String[] TableNo, MachineId, ItemName, Quantity, Progress, Timer;
    private ItemLayoutListViewAdapter(Context context, String[] aTableNo,                      String[] aMachineId, String[] aItemName, String[] aQuantity,
        String[] aProgress, String[] aTimer) {
        this.TableNo = aTableNo;
        this.MachineId = aMachineId;
        this.ItemName = aItemName;
        this.Quantity = aQuantity;
        this.Progress = aProgress;
        this.Timer = aTimer;
        this.context = context;
    } 

    private class Hold {
        TextView[] tvItemLayoutListItems = new TextView[6];
        ImageButton ibItemCustomization, ibCorrect, ibWrong;
        ImageButton[] ibUpDownArrow = new ImageButton[2];
        Button bnProgress;
        Chronometer chTimer;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return TableNo.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        return arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
        if (arg1 == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        arg1=inflater.inflate(R.layout.kitchen_item_list_view_layout,null);
            myHold = new Hold();
            int[] tvItemLayoutListItemsIds = { R.id.tvTableNo,
                    R.id.tvMachineId, R.id.tvItemName,                                  R.id.tvQuantity,R.id.tvTimer, R.id.tvDummyItemName };
            int[] ibUpDownArrowIds = { R.id.ibArrowUp, R.id.ibArrowDown };
    for(int itvItemLayoutListItemsIdsCtr = 0; itvItemLayoutListItemsIdsCtr < tvItemLayoutListItemsIds.length;itvItemLayoutListItemsIdsCtr++) {
                myHold.tvItemLayoutListItems[itvItemLayoutListItemsIdsCtr] = (TextView) arg1
                        .findViewById(tvItemLayoutListItemsIds[itvItemLayoutListItemsIdsCtr]);

            }
            myHold.chTimer = (Chronometer) arg1.findViewById(R.id.chTimer);
            myHold.bnProgress = (Button) arg1.findViewById(R.id.bnProgress);
            myHold.tvItemLayoutListItems[0].setText(TableNo[arg0]);
            myHold.tvItemLayoutListItems[1].setText(MachineId[arg0]);
            myHold.tvItemLayoutListItems[2].setText(ItemName[arg0]);
            myHold.tvItemLayoutListItems[3].setText(Quantity[arg0]);
            myHold.tvItemLayoutListItems[4].setText(Timer[arg0]);
            myHold.ibCorrect = (ImageButton) arg1
                    .findViewById(R.id.ibCorrect);
            myHold.ibCorrect.setTag(myHold);
            myHold.ibCorrect.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    Hold Itemholder;
                    Itemholder = (Hold) arg0.getTag();
                    if (Itemholder.tvItemLayoutListItems[5].getText()
                            .equals("Orange")) {
                        Itemholder.tvItemLayoutListItems[2]
                                .setBackground(context.getResources()
                                        .getDrawable(
                                                R.drawable.textview_green));
                    } else {
                        Itemholder.tvItemLayoutListItems[2]
                                .setBackground(context.getResources()
                                        .getDrawable(
                                                R.drawable.textview_orange));
                        ;
                        Itemholder.tvItemLayoutListItems[5]
                                .setText("Orange");
                    }

                }
            });
            myHold.ibWrong = (ImageButton) arg1.findViewById(R.id.ibWrong);
            myHold.ibWrong.setTag(myHold);
            myHold.ibWrong.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    Hold Itemholder;
                    Itemholder = (Hold) arg0.getTag();
                    Itemholder.tvItemLayoutListItems[2]
                            .setBackground(context
                                    .getResources()
                                    .getDrawable(R.drawable.textview_border));

                }
            });

            myHold.ibItemCustomization = (ImageButton) arg1
                    .findViewById(R.id.ibItemCustomization);
            myHold.ibItemCustomization
                    .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View arg0) {
                            new item_customization(context).CustomizeItem();

                        }
                    });

            for (int iibUpDownArrowIdsCtr = 0; iibUpDownArrowIdsCtr < ibUpDownArrowIds.length; iibUpDownArrowIdsCtr++) {
                myHold.ibUpDownArrow[iibUpDownArrowIdsCtr] = (ImageButton) arg1
                        .findViewById(ibUpDownArrowIds[iibUpDownArrowIdsCtr]);
                myHold.ibUpDownArrow[iibUpDownArrowIdsCtr].setTag(myHold);
            }

            myHold.ibUpDownArrow[0]
                    .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View arg0) {
                            IncDecTimer(arg0,true);
                        }
                    });
            myHold.ibUpDownArrow[1]
                    .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View arg0) {
                            IncDecTimer(arg0,false);

                        }
                    });
            myHold.chTimer.setTag(myHold);
            myHold.tvItemLayoutListItems[4].setTag(myHold);
            myHold.chTimer.setBase(1000);
            myHold.chTimer.start();

            myHold.chTimer
                    .setOnChronometerTickListener(new OnChronometerTickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer arg0) {
                            final Hold Timerholder;
                            Timerholder = (Hold) arg0.getTag();
                            String[] sTimer = Timerholder.tvItemLayoutListItems[4]
                                    .getText().toString().split(":");
                            int iMin, iSec, iSecValue;

                            iMin = Integer.parseInt(sTimer[0]);
                            iSec = Integer.parseInt(sTimer[1]);

                            if (iSec == 0) {
                                iMin = iMin - 1;
                                if (iMin == -1) {
                                    Timerholder.tvItemLayoutListItems[4]
                                            .setText("00:00");
                                    Timerholder.chTimer.stop();
                                }
                                iSecValue = 60;
                            } else {
                                iSecValue = iSec;
                            }

                            iSecValue = iSecValue - 1;

                            String sMin, sSec;

                            if (iMin < 10) {
                                sMin = "0";

                            } else {
                                sMin = "";
                            }
                            if (iSecValue < 10) {
                                sSec = "0";

                            } else {
                                sSec = "";
                            }
                            if (iMin > -1) {
                                Timerholder.tvItemLayoutListItems[4].setText(sMin
                                        .concat(String.valueOf(iMin))
                                        .concat(":").concat(sSec)
                                        .concat(String.valueOf(iSecValue)));
                            }

                        }
                    });

            arg1.setTag(myHold);
        } else {
            arg1.getTag();
        }
        return arg1;
    }
```

Please do help me. If you need the code is please let me know. I have kept the basic custom listview with text view inside it.

Comment: Show Your Code...!!!!

Comment: google for listview view recycle

Comment: Show me only the getView method of your ListView Adapter class , I'll help you fix this.

Comment: I have updated the code. can you please help me out..